# Why is $f(x)$ not differentiable at 0?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given $f(x) = x^2$ when $x\leq 0$ and $x^2 + 1$ when $x>0$

I don't understand how $f'(0)$ doesn't exist. The the differential seems to be $0$ as you approach $0^-$ and $0^+$ so how does it not exist?

Thanks for any help in advance ♥

Comment: I believe you mean $f(x)=x^2+1$ when $x\gt 0$. If that is the case then $f$ approaches $1$ when taking the limit from the right. Also, $f(0$ does exist. Were you asking why $f'(0)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: If that is indeed OP’s intent @JohnDouma, and if his question really was about differentiability, then since diff $\Longrightarrow$ contin, your argument shows nondifferentiability.

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$$
But the limit as $h\to0$ of $f(h)$ does not exist as the limit from the positive and negative sides ($h\to0^+$ and $h\to0^-$) result is different values of $f(h)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x<0\to f'(x)=2x,\\x>0\to f'(x)=2x.$$

The limit of the derivative at $0$ does exist and is indeed $0$. That doesn't mean that the derivative itself exists. Because of the discontinuity, at least one of the left or right derivatives cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

*Draw* the segment from $(0,f(0))$ to $(x,f(x))$ for $x$ positive near $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$, since

1)$\lim_{ x \rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=0$.

2)$\lim_{ x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)=1$.

Hence not differentiable at $x=0.$